# Assistance using respond_to to find the right actions to render PDF in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf-generation, princely

I am trying out Prince with the Princely plugin, which is supposed to format templates that have the .pdf into a PDF generator.

Here is my controller:

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController

  def show_date
    @date = Date.today

    @campaigns = Campaign.all

    @contacts = Contact.all

    @contacts.each do |contact|

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "filename", :stylesheets => ["application", "prince"], :layout => "pdf"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I changed the routes.db to include the following:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action.:format'

  map.todo "todo/today",
            :controller => "todo",
            :action => "show_date"
```

My expected behavior is when I enter todo/today.pdf, it tries to execute show_date, but renders according to the princely plugin.

Right now, it says cannot find action.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the default route line (the first `map.connect`) below the `map.todo` line.

routes.rb is matching the first rule and looking for a `today` action.

Comment: Yes, the <code>map.connect</code> is below the map.todo ... do I need to explicitly state the template?  I thought it would use the same name as the Action....

Comment: Oh, maybe you have a map.resources line in there somewhere?

In an entry or an answer, but not a comment, you can highlight the part of your text that is code and then click on the little binary button to give it code highlighting.